# R-plot a centered legend at outer margins of multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to plot a centered legend outside of the plotting area in a device having multiple plots. There has been many questions (with slight variations) asked in SO about changing the position of legend in a R plot.

For example:

1) [R - Common title and legend for combined plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736966/r-common-title-and-legend-for-combined-plots)

2) [Common legend for multiple plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389967/common-legend-for-multiple-plots-in-r?rq=1)

3) [Plot a legend outside of the plotting area in base graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics?rq=1)

etc.

Now what I understood from the above questions is that I got to set the option `xpd = T` or `xpd = NA`to plot legends at the outer margins. However when I try this, it somehow does not work for me ..

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2),oma=c(0,3,0,0),xpd=TRUE)

plot(c(5,10),col=c("red","blue"),pch=20,cex=2,bty="n",xlab="",ylab="")
barplot(c(5,10),col=c("red","blue"))

mtext(text="My two plots",side=3,cex=2,outer=TRUE,line=-3)

legend("top",legend=c("A", "B"),fill=c("red","blue"),ncol=2,xpd=NA,bty="n")  # Option 1
legend(x=0.01,y=11,legend=c("A", "B"),fill=c("red","blue"),ncol=2,xpd=TRUE,bty="n") # Option 2
```

Now my question is, how does `xpd` exactly work ? as I am unable to figure out why shouldn't the legend not be placed outside the plot area with `xpd=T`.

I apologize in advance if some consider this as a duplicate of the above questions !!

Help is much appreciated

Ashwin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option #1 is likely the route you should take, with `xpd=NA`.  It does not automatically place the legend in the outer margins, but it ***allows you*** to place the legend anywhere you want.  So, for example, you could use this code to place the legend at the top of the page, approximately centered.

```
legend(x=-1.6, y=11.6, legend=c("A", "B"), fill=c("red", "blue"), ncol=2, xpd=NA, bty="n")
```

I chose these x and y values by trial and error.  But, you could define a function that overlays a single (invisible) plot on top of the ones you created.  Then you can use `legend("top", ...)`.  For example

```
reset <- function() {
    par(mfrow=c(1, 1), oma=rep(0, 4), mar=rep(0, 4), new=TRUE)
    plot(0:1, 0:1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
    }

reset()
legend("top", legend=c("A", "B"), fill=c("red", "blue"), ncol=2, bty="n")
```

Comment: Cool thanks.. is there anyway to automatically determine the x and y values or does that need to be determined by trail and error ??

Comment: You could use a workaround ... like overlaying one plot over the other two, so that you can then just call `legend("top", ...)`.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a hard time to get coordinates on the margins. I think I found a solution, you can specify coordinates for the legend using:
**getCoords()** function.

Look also to **legend_margin** function from plotfunctions package.
So combining the solution from Jean V. Adams with one of these functions should get you there.
Hope that works :)