# Plotting legend outside of multiple plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to plot the legend outside of multiple plot use this code:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
    par(oma = c(4, 2, 1, 1))
    plot(1)
    plot(2)
    plot(3)
    plot(4)
    plot(5)
    plot(6)
    plot(7)
    plot(8)
    plot(9)
    legend("bottom", inset = 0, legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), col= c("steelblue4", "lightseagreen", "paleturquoise", "gray87"),  bty = "n", horiz = T,  lwd = 5, xpd = T)
```

But the legend is inside of one of plot region:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: [Common legend for multiple plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391001/1851712); [R-plot a centered legend at outer margins of multiple plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082485/r-plot-a-centered-legend-at-outer-margins-of-multiple-plots)

Comment: See also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lemon/vignettes/legends.html

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html

Comment: @Tung I  use basic graphics, not ggplot...

Comment: @Henrik I read all of this topics and unfortunately none of this solutions work the problem for me...