# Common main title of a panel of plots

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have 2 plots in a panel via `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

```
op <- par(
  oma=c(0,0,3,0),# Room for the title and legend
  mfrow=c(1,2)
)
for(i in 1:2) {
  plot( cumsum(rnorm(100)), type="l", lwd=3,
  col=c("navy","orange")[ 1+i%%2 ], 
  las=1, ylab="Value",
  main=paste("Random data", i) )
}
```

I would like to plot main title "Random plots" which will fit nicely in the middle of the 2 plots.

I tried the solution from here [R - Common title and legend for combined plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736966/r-common-title-and-legend-for-combined-plots) using mtext and a lot of experimenting **but**  the `mtext` solution does not get the title exactly in the middle, just like the `main` argument of `plot()`.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: `title('my title', outer = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! please post as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: For future reference, you might also find `layout` useful in base graphics. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198767/how-to-annotate-across-or-between-plots-in-multi-plot-panels-in-r) addresses annotating across groups of plots using `layout`.